# changing TreeNode backColor with AfterSelect event not working as expected

Tags: c#

In my form there is a treeView listing persons and a ListBox listing person priviliges. Selecting a person refreshes the ListBox to show the applicable list of priviliges. The priviliges can be edited. When after edit the user selects another person in the tree, there is a message "Save changes?" with 3 buttons: Yes; No; Cancel. The calcel button is meant to return the treeView to the previous state, ie. the previous person selected and the one the user clicked - unselected.

To achieve this I tried using two event handlers on the treeView: BeforeSelect and AfterSelect. The code snippet goes as below. MyMessageBox is a class which returns an Enum value depending on which button is clicked

```
private void TreeView_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveButton.Enabled)
        {
            MyMessageBoxResults result = MyMessageBox.display("Save changes?", MessageBoxType.YesNoCancel);
            if (result == MyMessageBoxResults.Yes)
            {
                saveChanges();
            }
            else if (result == MyMessageBoxResults.Cancel)
            {
                TreeNode temp1 = TreeView.SelectedNode;         //for debug purposes
                temp1.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
                temp1.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else     //result == MyMessageBoxResults.No
            {

            }
        }
    }

private void TreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
TreeNode temp2 = TreeView.SelectedNode;         //for debug purposes
temp2.BackColor = TreeView.BackColor;
}
```

The result is that there are two nodes highlighted (ie. appear "selected" to the user). When debugging temp1 and temp2 nodes show values as expected, the color of TreeNode temp2 is shown as changed, so I would expect it to show the same in the TreeView, however it is white letters on blue. (There is some more code which actually selects the appropriate node, so the program as such works as expected, this is just the visual effects that are the problem). 
Any ideas?

Comment: It is unclear to me how changing the fore/backcolor of a node could be useful.  Don't do that, you need to set e.Cancel = true in the BeforeSelect event handler to prevent selection.

Comment: thank you, I never thought of that and this is just what I needed. As far as I am concerned - problem solved.